# MacOS AppKit - how to change the color of the close, minimize and maximize buttons "standardWindowButton"

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsbutton

I need to change the default red, yellow and green colors to be something else. The MacOS Preview (click on file and press spacebar) has a white/grey background for the buttons. I need that in my app.

I am able to get the buttons by `view.window?.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)` but am unable to change the color. So far I have tried this:

```
view.window?.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.wantsLayer = true
view.window?.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.layer?.backgroundColor = .black
```

but it changes the background square color and not the `red`. If I print the button, it does print as a NSButton.

Comment: You could certainly make a borderless window and just draw everything yourself, but obviously there are many problems with that.  If you want specifically the appearance of the Finder's preview windows, I think they are HUD type windows, which you can make in Interface Builder / Cocoa with a flag passed to the window constructor.

Comment: Do you want to use the window to show a preview of a file?

Comment: @Willeke no, I am using it for a window which is always on top of everything using "floating" level. My UI would look much better if I could use different color than the default one.